# How to access the list properties in API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two classes, Students Request Model and Students Response Model, both contains same properties. A student can have one or more departments

I have class name `Students`  and another class name `Departments`, I am working a simple web API.

```
 public class Students
    {
      public string StudentId{ get; set; }
      public string StudentName{ get; set; }
      public List<Departments> Department{ get; set; } 
    }

Department Class:
     public class Departments
     {
      public string DepartmentId{ get; set; }
      public string DepartmentName{ get; set; }
     }
```

This is the controller method I created,

```
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] Students request)
        {
            var response = new Response
            {
                StudentId = request.StudentId,
                StudentName = request.StudentName,
                Department = new Department 
                {
                 // this is where I am trying to figure it out how to map those properties from                  request.
                 // there may one or more departments.
                 // I am trying any, but it is not working
                }
                
            };
            //
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

Please help

How to map the virtual Properties?

Comment: How you post your Students request? Do you set a breakpoint at  Get([FromQuery] Students request) to see the value of Department ? Could you get your Department in  request?

Comment: Yes I set breakpoint in Get. I am trying to consume this API from console application, so from console application I am going to send some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Students Request Model and Students Response Model, both contains same
> properties.

I guess your Students Response Model like:

```
public class Response
    {
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public List<Departments> Department { get; set; }
    }
```

You can refer to my code to map your virtual Properties:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] Students request)
        {
            var response = new Response
            {
                StudentId = request.StudentId,
                StudentName = request.StudentName,
                Department =request.Department                

            };                
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

Request example:

```
https://localhost:7121/api/St/?Department[0].DepartmentId=123&Department[0].DepartmentName=blah&Department[1].DepartmentId=145&Department[1].DepartmentName=jj&StudentId=1&StudentName=ww
```

result:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work me, cannot implicitly convert issue.

Comment: @MinhajuddinKhaja  Could you share you console code about "send some parameters"? And how you  consume this API from console application ?